# react + asp.net core separate projects hosting (deploy)suggestion

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, iis, hosting, web-deployment

i have two projects client for front-end and server for back-end.both working fine independantly and communication on local host. so react app with asp.netcore back-end.

client is built using vs code and i start by typing "npm start" on terminal.
server is built using visual studio 2019 , it works as webapi and i start simply typing "dotnet run" on cmd in server folder ,or from vs f5 command.

anyone suggest how to build or publish both and start them for production .any suggestion other than azure .
if i am wrong ,how to merge both and host on single server .
client folder structure is here:
[image: client]

server (webapi) structure is here:
[image: server webapi here]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you posted two thumbnails by mistake, please post the origin srcreenshot picture.

Since your client for front-end and server for back-end can work independently, you can create two websites in iis and then publish your projects separately. About how to publish an ASP.NET Core app to IIS you can refer to this link:[Publish an ASP.NET Core app to IIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/publish-to-iis?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio)

Comment: hi @samwu very thanks for help.it mean i have to purchase hosting for two websites on iis. if am not wrong i need windows hosting for two websites.client and webapi(back-end asp.netcore) work independently .but i have purchased single domain .thanks in advance for clearance.

Comment: hi @samwu i have edited question for clear pictures .waiting for your suggestion.

Comment: If you only purchased a single domain, then you can use a different port, or you can use sub-app to publish them under the same website.